# Do I absolutely need SOL to sell or swap USDC?

Tags: wallet, usdc

I'm trying to ramp off USDC from my Brave Wallet but I don't have SOL, do I need to buy some just to get rid of (swap or sell) USDC?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a trivial amount of SOL (<.001) to open your token account for USDC, and to pay the tx fee (currently .0005 SOL).

Most people end up using a CEX for this step. Unfortunately there isn't a good decentralized way to fund your initial SOL balance.